# Property 'r' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, svelte

I'm trying to get the radius of a circle svg element but a error is coming in vs code:

actual code:

```
const circle = document.getElementById('progress_circle');
const radius = circle.r.baseVal.value;
```

error:

```
Property 'r' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.js(2339)
```

I'm using svelte, ts and vs code and *I'm also a newbie in web dev*.

Comment: That's correct. An HTMLElement doesn't have a property `r`.

Comment: then what can i use to get the radius of a circle?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025171/changing-properties-of-svg-circle-in-html5-js/25025293

Comment: If `r` is an attribute of the element you fetched (I assume it's a svg circle?), you need to use `getAttribute('r')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got to a solution thanks to @aerial301

```
const circle = document.getElementById('progress_circle');
const radius = +circle.getAttribute('r');
```

reference: [Changing properties of SVG circle in HTML5/JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25025171/changing-properties-of-svg-circle-in-html5-js/25025293)